# Application without app icon

Tags: android

I plan to do an app which contains only one activity and without any app icon, where I need to open this activity by using the keypad. Say for example, whenever you dial `12345` my application activity should open without an app icon. Is this possible in Android? How?

Comment: Did you find solution? if yes, i would appreciate if you can share the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify drawable resource for `android:icon` attribute in `application` element of `AndroidManifest.xml`. From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#icon):

> This attribute must be set as a reference to a drawable resource containing the image (for example "@drawable/icon"). There is no default icon.

---

But the drawable specified doesn't need to be an icon. It can be defined as color in your resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <drawable name="color_icon">#ff0000</drawable>
</resources>
```

And then specify it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>  
    <application android:icon="@drawable/color_icon" ...>
       ...
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

And you'll see something like this in your application launchpad:

[image]

Comment: To prevent an icon from showing in the app drawer, refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174993/android-app-without-icon/14175020#14175020

Answer (score 13):

Just remove **android.intent.category.LAUNCHER** from your main Activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**

And you cannot open app by dialing `*#*#12345#*#*` because in order to do that you have to write a receiver for following action

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
```

Then you can open your app by firing an Intent from that broadcast receiver. **But android does not permit this until your app is **System app***.*

Following is the code that will help you
Change activity in Manifest to have no intent filters like

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyApp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_parent_trap"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        </activity>
<receiver android:name=".MyApp$Launch" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />

                <data
                    android:host="(secret code)"
                    android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Once done, make a class (I made the Launch class in my main class, extending BroadCast Receiver), then in the onReceive class, fire an intent to launch the activity.

Then typing `*#*#(secret code)#*#*` into the dialer will launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

just Remove "category" Tag  from manifest file

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.airplanemode.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```