# android app without icon

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application without app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426389/application-without-app-icon)

My question is very straight forward. I want to create an Android app without any icon.
My app requires only two services which will be launched at boot up.
 Is it possible ? 
I am asking this question because I came to know about this app **SMS tracker Agent**. Here's [a link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gizmoquip.smstracker&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5naXptb3F1aXAuc21zdHJhY2tlciJd)! And this app actually does this so I think it is possible.
I installed this app in my Samsung Galaxy note having Android version 4.0.3 and I can only see app icon in list of application installed in settings but not in main app icon screen. So please any one can tell me how the did or any other way of doing this.
My Question is related to this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426389/application-without-app-icon) but I didn't get what I wanted.
I am very newbie to this site. So please advice me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes that's possible. To have the icon show up in the device app drawer you would use this intent filter in your manifest.xml which you can just leave out:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: this is giving error: Error launching activity