# Android hidden app

Tags: android, security, hidden, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application without app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426389/application-without-app-icon)

I want to create security - app. I want to hide the icon of app on launcher (user can't see them) after configuration. I tried to use service, but this isn't good solution, because I see still icon . I heard about editing mainfest, but i can't make them.Please, help me, and don't remove my post. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an answer to your needs: http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-android-application-with-no.html?m=0

Comment: Thanks, but I want to hide icon after configuration and not after installation.

Comment: @Ty221 So you want the application on the launcher but with no icon? But you want the user to specify whether they want to?

Comment: no, after install icon should be on launcher, but after configuration icon should be deleted

Comment: @Ty221 You could create a seperate application that just installs your applications .apk, and once its installed, the application removes the icon, of I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: yes, it's true. now i want to read about installng apk packets. Very, very thanks. If you want you can write this as answer

Comment: augh, i have one more problem ! How can I make configuration screen ????

Comment: augh, i have one more problem ! How can I make configuration screen ????

Comment: Make the configuration screen part of the initial application that installs the apk. So first it asks for the configuration then it stores it onto the phones memory card, etc. Then the app installs the real app and uninstalls itself and its icon. Then the real application refers to the configuration stored on the memory card, and runs accordingly. So in short, 1 app sets it up, another refers to what the initial app set up.

Comment: Very thanks, you are expert :).

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is removing the line

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
```

from your manifest, which tells Android that the activity you've put it into should appear in the launcher.

HOWEVER, it's not a good idea to hide your application from the launcher, as then the average user won't know how to find it to reconfigure/remove it as necessary.

Comment: Yes, very thanks. It's good, because this program is parental controler. But I want to hide icon after configuration and not after installation

Comment: replace the application by the no-icon version after the config is done

Comment: no, this isn't duplicate

Comment: i wrote them. " I want to hide the icon of app on launcher (user can't see them) after configuration."